# Issues with dotenv import in Junyper lab notebook

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

In a jupyter notebook I run the following code which installs all the dependencies for monai and torchtext,

```
!pip install -r source/requirements.txt
```

and then tries to import the following...

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
env_path = Path('.') / 'set.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

The environment file has these variables set:

```
# EDIT: S3 bucket and folder where you uploaded dataverse_file.zip
BUCKET='https://imaging-input.s3.amazonaws.com'
BUCKET_PATH='/dataset'
```

but the notebook throws an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

On line 3 trying to import **dotenv**. I'm using the conda_python3 kernel, and tried several different kernels, installing dotenv from the terminal. I'm not sure what's happening or what I'm missing here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing your `requirements.txt` file, my guess is it either does not include `python-dotenv` or it includes `dotenv` instead. The one you want is `python-dotenv`. Either add it to your requirements file or install it independently (i.e. `!pip install python-dotenv`)

Comment: @jeff that was the issue, thank you.